# Getting movie path

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, uiwebview

My question is: How can I get full path of embedded movie played with `WebView`?
I have link to embeded video. like    http://www.youtube.com/embed/eZ-SBtUInVY

Then I play it I get `NSLog` from **Apple** like :

```
  setting movie path: http://r2---sn-gvnuxaxjvh-3bqe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1399003124&mv=m&source=youtube&ratebypass=yes&signature=471986566CED342721806219ED9832F2E1472285.6A36B27ABA52E84481624C0DC9E49A1CBA189035&key=yt5&mt=1398980522&id=799f9206d5089d56&sver=3&fexp=903903%2C911429%2C930802%2C945110%2C916623%2C919116%2C937417%2C913434%2C923341%2C936923&sparams=id%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&upn=uSChP8VUmjk&itag=18&mws=yes&ipbits=0&ip=178.68.55.93&ms=au&cpn=y6Ydw8KJGizaTSA7&ptk=theorchardmusic&oid=J8vAyKuNSYBIN_9RIdxggQ&pltype=contentugc&c=WEB&cver=html5

  RTCReporting: resolve from http://pancake.apple.com/bags/hls?version=4.12
```

And then sometimes goes error. -- I looked here for this and find that it ok for playing embeded with webView

My code

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame: (CGRectEqualToRect(frame, CGRectZero) ? CGRectMake(50, 50, 250, 250) : frame)];
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Comment: Please try to make your "Question" net & explain details about your exact point of need. If it's about "code", then provide it in details. If you face with some `error` then show them too. And overall try to follow the `stackoverflow` "Ask question" rules and regulations. By following this the possibility of getting your question's answer is high. Enjoy.
-Thanks.

Comment: @user3587674: Am getting the same error while playing video. How did u fix it. Is it working fine in both iOS 6 and 7?